# Search for the best spelling and grammar checking tool for English language

Tags: language, spell-check, english, grammar

I am searching for the best spelling and grammar checking tool for English language.
I have no problem to buy this tool as long as it runs under linux (OpenOffice)...

Comment: Last time I looked grammar checkers were few and far between. I'll be interested to see if you get any decent replies on that.

Comment: I did once find a plug-in for OpenOffice (now called something else, I think) that did English grammar checking. You can probably find it by searching their plugin site. It was OK, but not great. And it was free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out:

https://superuser.com/questions/84284/what-about-a-good-software-to-check-grammar-in-english-language

https://superuser.com/questions/257395/grammar-and-spelling-checking-software

and

https://superuser.com/questions/95441/which-is-best-free-online-offine-service-tool-to-check-correctness-of-grammar-of

For some suggestions.  Personally, I have used after the deadling for open office and found it useful enough.

S

Comment: The links are all dead by now

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunspell

- Despite its name, it is not for Hungarian alone anymore
- Open Source
- Run on Open Office
- Fairly well-known
- Probably less powerful than AfterTheDeadline/Polishmywriting.com

AfterTheDeadline

- Powerful, it can check style too
- Open Source
- Run on Open Office -(there is also a web-based version at Polishmywriting.com, but I could not achieve comparable results - browser-based versions exist too, making it legible for Google's OpenOffice, Google Drive)
- Well-known
- Still room to grow compared to some proprietary software (but here I am talking about spellchecker for French, not for English, so I can't compare)